# Define UserControl within a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to define a UserControl within a ResourceDictionary, and then add it to a component within the same XAML file?  Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        etc.>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <UserControl x:Key="MyCustomLabel">
                <Label Content="Foo"/>
                ...lots more here
            </UserControl> 
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <MyCustomLabel />  //This doesn't work
        <MyCustomLabel />
        <MyCustomLabel />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I could define it in its own file, but I really only need it as a subcomponent within this file.  I'd use a Style, but I don't know of a way to style the content of each row of my Grid.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does your `CustomLabel` do? How is it different from a regular `Label`? Why is `Style TargetType="Label"` not a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `DataTemplate` resource and a `ContentPresenter` control. Here is an example which works analogously with your `UserControl`:

```
<Window>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
            <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>            
    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel Margin="35">
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Content="Hallo" />
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Content="123" />
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Content="ABC" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

The `ContentControls` render as:

[image: Rendered]

Just replace `Button` with your own control and it should do what you want...